# Adding variable to get_template_part

Tags: templates, page-template, variables

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/component-page/component-$variable); ?>
```

What is the correct way to add a variable to where I currently have $variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're just trying to concatenate a string, so it can be done like this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/component-page/component-' . $variable ); ?>
```

Or you could use string interpolation (note the double quotes used here):

```
<?php get_template_part( "template-parts/component-page/component-{$variable}" ); ?>
```

Alternatively, [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) can take two parameters, `$slug` and `$name`:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/component-page/component', $variable ); ?>
```